# hide select box options in contributed page

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page, price-sets, javascript

I am currently trying to edit : sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.tpl

to try and alter when select box A of pricesets are chosen then hide an option in select box B, as I understand civi used a different kind of jquery select box is there anyway I can hide it so that the options do not come available as I already hide the original   part but its still available

thank you

Answer (score 2):

First - don't edit anything in the templates_c directory!  These are cached pre-compiled copies of the template, and are frequently cleared out.

Second - it's not advisable to edit the templates that ship with CiviCRM directly, because you'll have to apply your changes on every upgrade.

The best practice is to install [civix](https://github.com/totten/civix) and create an extension, but in your case, I don't see the harm of using a template override, and more specifically a ".extra.tpl" file.

[This wiki page](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Page+Templates) has all the information you need.  I would start by just creating a "custom templates" directory, and make sure you can successfully implement your change with a normal template override.  Then remove your override and reimplement using a .extra.tpl file, and your change should be OK through most upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

With Drupal you can easily inject some JS for specific CiviCRM URLs - this example is for an event/registration page - but this should work for all urls.

```
function myorg_zen_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
    if (strpos(request_path(), 'civicrm/event/register') === 0) {
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'myorg_zen') . '/js/civicrm-event-register.js');
    }
}
```

and then in that js file - you can add all the js you need/want to change/re-arrange the elements on that civicrm page. Things we often do:

- show/hide custom fields based on change in the price option selected
- replace the ugly black CiviCRM buttons with nice colorful modern sass
  buttons
- style the #google_map
- control whether the default for is_recurring on contribution pages
  that allow recurring contributions - is checked - or not